# How can I pass the match of a Kleene closure to my action in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr

I have the following production in my ANTLR grammar:

```
rich_newick_string 
:    str=(.*';') { stack.pushRichNewickString($str.text); };
```

I expected some string match to be passed to my pushRichNewickString method, but instead I'm getting null. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put more than one lexer/parser rule inside parenthesis and then assign a label to it:

```
rule
  :   label=(ruleA ruleB ruleC) { /* use $label.text in here */ }
  ;
```

Try this instead:

```
rule
  :   label=tempRule { /* use $label.text in here */ }
  ;

tempRule
  :  ruleA ruleB ruleC
  ;
```

Also, do you really have a `.*` inside your parser rule? Are you aware this does *not* match **zero or more characters**, but **zero or more tokens** instead?